# Exponential smoothing in statsmodels gives error

Tags: python, time-series, statsmodels

I am trying to apply Holt-winter exponencial smoothing and in stastsmodels there is still a error

```
data = Airpassengers
from statsmodels.tsa.api import ExponentialSmoothing, SimpleExpSmoothing, Holt
data["exp"] = ExponentialSmoothing(data["Passengers"], seasonal="mul", seasonal_periods=12).fit()
```

```
ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'double' but got 'long long'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to cast your data like this :

```
data["exp"] = ExponentialSmoothing(data["Passengers"].astype(np.int64), seasonal="mul", seasonal_periods=12).fit()
```